# How to create @Html.myname in MVC View intellisense?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, intellisense

If I type `@Html.` in a View of MVC, intellisense will automatically show like 'Action', 'Actionlink' etc. I need to add my name in the intellisense. How to do that?

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product_Id)
```

In the above line I need to create my name in the intellisense as `@Html.sathiya`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write a helper static class to extend HtmlHelper class:

```
namespace MyProject.Extensions
{
  public static class HtmlHelperExts
  {
    public static string sathiya(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
      return "qwerty";
    }
  }
}
```

Now u can use it (don't forget to import namespace before using) at your view:

```
@using MyProject.Extensions
@Html.sathiya()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What namespace I need to give?

Comment: Namespance, where u defined that class. I have edited my answer, check

Comment: Actually I don't understand where to place this code? Where to write that helper static class? Can you please elaborate it? It will help me a lot.

Comment: Create a new .cs file anywhere you want in your web project and place this code there. If you want to place this code in another project (library e.g.) - don't forget to add a reference in your web project to that library project.